# Trying to join 3 statements

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT       INS_PRODUCT, SR_AREA, RESOLUTION_CD, COUNT(*) AS Vol        
FROM S_SRV_REQ          
WHERE  (INS_PRODUCT = 'Mobl Hlth') AND (CREATED BETWEEN '10/1/2014' AND '09/30/2015') and (SR_AREA IS NOT NULL)    
GROUP BY INS_PRODUCT, SR_AREA, RESOLUTION_CD
ORDER BY INS_PRODUCT, SR_AREA, RESOLUTION_CD

SELECT       INS_PRODUCT, SR_AREA, RESOLUTION_CD, COUNT(*) AS Vol        
FROM S_SRV_REQ          
WHERE  (INS_PRODUCT = 'MHV') AND (CREATED BETWEEN '10/1/2014' AND '09/30/2015') and (SR_AREA IS NOT NULL)    
GROUP BY INS_PRODUCT, SR_AREA, RESOLUTION_CD
ORDER BY INS_PRODUCT, SR_AREA, RESOLUTION_CD

SELECT       INS_PRODUCT, SR_AREA, RESOLUTION_CD, COUNT(*) AS Vol        
FROM S_SRV_REQ          
WHERE  (INS_PRODUCT = 'eBenefits') AND (CREATED BETWEEN '10/1/2014' AND '09/30/2015') and (SR_AREA IS NOT NULL)    
GROUP BY INS_PRODUCT, SR_AREA, RESOLUTION_CD
ORDER BY INS_PRODUCT, SR_AREA, RESOLUTION_CD
```

Each code is pull different information I need

Comment: have you tried "UNION"

Comment: Show us some data, db schema and expected result. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the `WHERE` clauses together:

```
SELECT INS_PRODUCT, SR_AREA, RESOLUTION_CD, COUNT(*) AS Vol        
FROM S_SRV_REQ          
WHERE SR_AREA IS NOT NULL
AND CREATED BETWEEN '10/1/2014' AND '09/30/2015'
AND INS_PRODUCT IN ('Mobl Hlth', 'MHV', 'eBenefits')
GROUP BY INS_PRODUCT, SR_AREA, RESOLUTION_CD
ORDER BY INS_PRODUCT, SR_AREA, RESOLUTION_CD
```

---

Or you can union them together:

```
SELECT INS_PRODUCT, SR_AREA, RESOLUTION_CD, COUNT(*) AS Vol        
FROM S_SRV_REQ          
WHERE  (INS_PRODUCT = 'Mobl Hlth') AND (CREATED BETWEEN '10/1/2014' AND '09/30/2015') and (SR_AREA IS NOT NULL)    
GROUP BY INS_PRODUCT, SR_AREA, RESOLUTION_CD

UNION ALL

SELECT INS_PRODUCT, SR_AREA, RESOLUTION_CD, COUNT(*) AS Vol        
FROM S_SRV_REQ          
WHERE  (INS_PRODUCT = 'MHV') AND (CREATED BETWEEN '10/1/2014' AND '09/30/2015') and (SR_AREA IS NOT NULL)    
GROUP BY INS_PRODUCT, SR_AREA, RESOLUTION_CD

UNION ALL

SELECT INS_PRODUCT, SR_AREA, RESOLUTION_CD, COUNT(*) AS Vol        
FROM S_SRV_REQ          
WHERE  (INS_PRODUCT = 'eBenefits') AND (CREATED BETWEEN '10/1/2014' AND '09/30/2015') and (SR_AREA IS NOT NULL)    
GROUP BY INS_PRODUCT, SR_AREA, RESOLUTION_CD
ORDER BY INS_PRODUCT, SR_AREA, RESOLUTION_CD
```

Two things to note: `UNION ALL` when you know your records don't overlap. This avoids the DB checking for duplicates.  Also, place just one `ORDER BY` at the end.

Comment: You revised your answer to be a copy of mine.  I don't care about the rep but come on man.

Comment: @Paparazzi Or you can look at my edit history and see I was combining the where clause 5 minutes before you.

Comment: OK but I did not copy you.  When I posted all that was on the screen was union.

Answer (score 1):

Uh

```
SELECT INS_PRODUCT, SR_AREA, RESOLUTION_CD, COUNT(*) AS Vol        
FROM S_SRV_REQ          
WHERE INS_PRODUCT IN ('eBenefits', 'MHV', 'Mobl Hlth') 
  AND CREATED BETWEEN '10/1/2014' AND '09/30/2015' 
  and SR_AREA IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY INS_PRODUCT, SR_AREA, RESOLUTION_CD
ORDER BY INS_PRODUCT, SR_AREA, RESOLUTION_CD
```

Comment: beat me just because some coworker distract me with some questions

Answer (score 0):

Since all else is the same in tour three selects you can combine them into a single one like

```
SELECT  INS_PRODUCT, SR_AREA, RESOLUTION_CD, COUNT(*) AS Vol        
FROM S_SRV_REQ          
WHERE  (INS_PRODUCT in ('Mobl Hlth','MHV','eBenefits')) AND (CREATED BETWEEN '10/1/2014' AND '09/30/2015') and (SR_AREA IS NOT NULL)    
GROUP BY INS_PRODUCT, SR_AREA, RESOLUTION_CD
ORDER BY INS_PRODUCT, SR_AREA, RESOLUTION_CD
```

Comment: Certainly true! I was just too slow on my smartphone ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  INS_PRODUCT, 
  SR_AREA, 
  RESOLUTION_CD, 
  SUM(IF(INS_PRODUCT = 'Mobl Hlth',1,0)) Mobl_Hlth_Cnt,
  SUM(IF(INS_PRODUCT = 'MHV',1,0)) MHV_Cnt,
  SUM(IF(INS_PRODUCT = 'eBenefits',1,0)) eBenefits_Cnt
FROM S_SRV_REQ          
WHERE INS_PRODUCT IN ('Mobl Hlth', 'MHV', 'eBenefits')
   AND (CREATED BETWEEN '10/1/2014' AND '09/30/2015') 
   AND (SR_AREA IS NOT NULL)    
GROUP BY INS_PRODUCT, SR_AREA, RESOLUTION_CD
ORDER BY INS_PRODUCT, SR_AREA, RESOLUTION_CD
```

or if my guess is correct you can remove `INS_PRODUCT` from `GROUP BY` so you get:

```
SELECT 
  SR_AREA, 
  RESOLUTION_CD, 
  SUM(IF(INS_PRODUCT = 'Mobl Hlth',1,0)) Mobl_Hlth_Cnt,
  SUM(IF(INS_PRODUCT = 'MHV',1,0)) MHV_Cnt,
  SUM(IF(INS_PRODUCT = 'eBenefits',1,0)) eBenefits_Cnt
FROM S_SRV_REQ          
WHERE INS_PRODUCT IN ('Mobl Hlth', 'MHV', 'eBenefits')
   AND (CREATED BETWEEN '10/1/2014' AND '09/30/2015') 
   AND (SR_AREA IS NOT NULL)    
GROUP BY SR_AREA, RESOLUTION_CD
ORDER BY SR_AREA, RESOLUTION_CD
```